# React-Redux : How to combine reducers with Thunk middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I started coding a web interface to manage my server's files using React/Redux.
I now have a page which requests my API to get files list as JSON.

It works well so I added another reducer and an action button to simply display the filename on click.
But combining my `datalist-reducer` with the `active-file reducer` doesn't work.
The files list creation process fails with the following error:

> TypeError: Undefined is not a function (near'...this.props.datalist.map...')

Thank you.

Here's my code :

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import activeFileReducer from './reducers/reducer-active-file';
import dataListReducer from './reducers/reducer-data';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    datalist: datalist, 
    activefile: activefile
})
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)
let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('table'));
```

datalist-reducer

```
export default function datalist (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_REQUEST":
            return state;
        case "FETCH_SUCCESS": 
            return {datalist: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

active-file-reducer

```
export default function activefile (state= {}, action){
        switch(action.type){
            case "FILE_SELECTED":
                return action.payload;
            default:
                return state;
        }

    }
```

actions/index.js

```
export const selectFile = (file) => {
    return {
        type: "FILE_SELECTED",
        payload: file
    }
}


export const fetchDataRequest = () =>{
    return {
      type: "FETCH_REQUEST"
    }
}

export const fetchDataSuccess = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
        payload
    }
}

export const fetchDataError = () => {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_ERROR"
    }
}
```

data-list-container

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchDataRequest, fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError, selectFile} from '../actions/index';

class DataList extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchDataWithRedux()

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.datalist && 
                    this.props.datalist.map((item, key) =>{
                        return(
                            <li key={key} onClick={() => this.props.selectFile(item.title)}>{item.title}</li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )       
    }
}


function fetchDataWithRedux() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchDataRequest());
        return fetchData().then(([response, json]) =>{
            console.log(response);
            if(response.status === 200){
            dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(json))
            dispatch(selectFile())
    }
    else{
        dispatch(fetchDataError())
        dispatch(selectFile())
    }
    })
}
}

function fetchData() {
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/deposit/view";
return fetch(URL, { method: 'GET'})
    .then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        datalist: state.datalist
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDataWithRedux})(DataList);
```

Comment: kindly share any code that you have written, will be of great help :)

Comment: more code please

Comment: Edited my post with my code. Thank you :)

Comment: selectFile may not have been passed, Check if it is defined

Comment: What do you suggest to check that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `index.js` file to something like:

```js
import { 
    createStore, 
    applyMiddleware, 
    combineReducers 
} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    datalist: datalist, 
    activefile: activefile
});

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('table')
);
```

NB: Added in missing imports (some guessed) for completeness.

Edit: Now that your reducers are combined, you need to amend your `datalist` reducer:

```js
// datalist-reducer
export default function datalist (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_REQUEST":
            return state;
        case "FETCH_SUCCESS": 
            return action.payload || [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is because, your `datalist` reducer will be given the `datalist` key from your store, and your `state` will be the contents of that key (or undefined on the first run).

Comment: Where is 'this.props.data.map'? I don't see it in your code above?

Comment: It's in datalist-container, it's 'this.props.datalist.map'

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work well. I have another question : how can I dispatch my action "selectFile" with the "FetchWithDataRedux" function. I get an error : TypeError: _this2.props.selectFile is not a function

Comment: Awesome, glad this solved your problem! P.S. Don't forget to mark this as the solution :) Can you share the bit of code that isn't working (including module imports -- as these are missing above)

Comment: I added the module imports in my first post. The code that doesn't work is in data-list-container I think. With your previous solution, now my page load without problem but when I select a file in the list (this should store the file name of the one I clicked), I get the error : TypeError : _this2.props.selectFile is not a function.

Comment: Ah, you haven't mapped `selectFile` within your `mapStateToProps` function :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created another post about this problem. The solution was to add 'selectFile' with the 'fetchDataWithRedux' function as follow : export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDataWithRedux, selectFile})(DataList);